# polymer retrieving data from sub elements

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have the following dom repeat, which basically takes an array of survey question and displays them.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{survey.Questions}}">
  <template is="dom-if" restamp if="{{isFormat(item.Type, 'Single-Select')}}">
    <question-singleselect question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-singleselect>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" restamp if="{{isFormat(item.Type,'Open-Ended')}}">
    <question-openended question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-openended>
  </template>
```

and in the code further down, I want to take the answers, and create the header record, and all the detail/answer records... The header, I can save no problem, the detail records, I am trying to do the following.

```
for(question in survey.Questions) 
{
   ...
}
```

Getting the error message, 'survey cannot be found'. How can I gain access to the array of questions that I am displaying on this page? I have tried this.$. and other different things I found on the web and this site.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of survey.questions. It seemed that I had to give the dom-repeat an ID and reference that ID with the following:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="testquestions" items="{{survey.Questions}}">
...
...
var item = this.$.testquestions;
```